# remote server CRON file does not add data to the table

Tags: php, mysql, cron, remote-server

im trying to write a query to insert data to my remote database table from a CRON file in my remote server. db connection happens through webservice and all that is working fine but the database does not get filled. following is the code that i have written, will anyone of you be able to find why it does not get write to the database table

```
$link = DbConnection::getInstance('TDC')->connectMysql()
$attributeKey = "12345";
$query_new = "INSERT INTO redtable (message) VALUES ('$attributeKey')";
$result = mysql_query($query_new, $link);
```

Comment: any debugging attempts made ?

Comment: i dont know how to debug in cron... this is actually an attempt for a indirect debugging :D.. do u have any idea about debugging cron??